# How to prevent cordova app from closing from backbutton - Android

Tags: javascript, android, vue.js, cordova, back-button

So I have searched and searched for a possible fix to this but here's my problem.
I have hooked up the backbutton event for cordova to listen for an Android device's back button event. It works just fine. I can get alerts and log statements... However, after the function executes, my app will close. My question is: **How can I prevent the app from closing at all from the back button?**

Here is my current code

```
document.addEventListener('backbutton', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      alert('Back Button Pressed')
      $logger?.silent('Back Button Pressed', e)
    }, false)
```

I'm using:

- Cordova 10.0.0
- Android: 9.0.0

```
cordova-android-support-gradle-release 3.0.1 "cordova-android-support-gradle-release"
cordova-pdf-generator 2.1.1 "PDFGenerator"
cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter 1.1.1 "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter"
cordova-plugin-appavailability 0.4.2 "AppAvailability"
cordova-plugin-background-mode 0.7.3 "BackgroundMode"
cordova-plugin-badge 0.8.8 "Badge"
cordova-plugin-barcodescanner 0.7.4 "BarcodeScanner"
cordova-plugin-camera 4.1.0 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.3 "Device"
cordova-plugin-document-viewer 1.0.0 "SitewaertsDocumentViewer"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.2 "File"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.2 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-honeywell-barcode-scanner 0.0.11 "HoneywellBarcodeScanner"
cordova-plugin-network-information 2.0.2 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-printer 0.8.0 "Printer"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 6.0.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.3 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.4 "Whitelist"
```

Comment: you might want to try to prevent propagation as well

Comment: @Eric Life savior bro :*

Answer (score 0):

I recommend setting the listener after the onReadyDevice event fires.